# Set $path fail (win10 subsystem linux, ubuntu, fish shell, brew)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, fish

### Environment

- OS: Windows Subsystem for Linux, Ubuntu 18.04
- shell: fish
- Tool kit management: brew (homebrew/linuxbrew)

  - fish had installed

    - fish had set as default shell
  - brew had installed

    - brew environment setting as [official site](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux)
    - php had installed with brew
    - composer had installed with brew

### target

I want to use PHP with "php" command which brew had installed but fail.

### What I had done

- I try to set environment by myself

  - Following success in current shell but fail when restart shell

  ```
  # in bash I tried these
  PATH=${PATH}:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/
  export PATH=${PATH}:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/

  # in fish bash I tried these
  set PATH $PATH /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/     <-update: updated
  export PATH $PATH:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/  <-update: wrong
  ```

  - Following success in bash but fail in fish

    - add the command above in .bashrc file in user directory
      (.bashrc seems only run when bash)
  - Following should success but fail

    - `sudo -H vi /etc/environment`
    - add `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/` in it

Comment: fish or bash? decide

Comment: I just want fish as default

Comment: I write bash here just because I found that .bashrc only run for bash rather than fish, or I might just use this as solution

Comment: Let me try it now

Comment: it seems fish didn't run .fishrc before start

Comment: That's because there is no such thing as a ".fishrc". The file is called "config.fish" and it is placed in ~/.config/fish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want commands to run when starting fish, you need to put them into a file called "config.fish" in ~/.config/fish/. Bashrc is, as the name implies, specific to *bash*.

Also "export" is used to mark a variable for "exporting", meaning passing it on to external commands the shell starts. $PATH is usually inherited from whatever starts the *shell*, which then means it's exported anyway, so your `export` line is useless.

Also your fish command needs a slight adjustment:

```
set PATH $PATH /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/
```

$PATH in fish is a list, and so it needs to be set as multiple arguments, not one string. In fish 3.0 (which was released after Ubuntu 18.04) this was adjusted to automatically split on ":", but even in that case you'll have to quote it or it will have surprising results.

Comment: Is the use of fish_user_paths deprecated?

Comment: It's not. I just didnt want to complicate this explanation.